# Can I add a calendar as a webpart if it is not in my site

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, web-part, calendar

I am in **Department A** that has a Parent site and multiple subsites
There is also a **Department B** that has its own Parent site and multiple subsites.  I have read access to **Department B**'s site.  I am owner of **Department A** site.

**Department B** would like me to add their calendar from their parent site into my site (**Department A**) as a web part.  Is this possible?  If so, how?

Answer (score 3):

Short answer: no, not out-of-the box.

Site collections (what you call "parent sites") are partionned containers, and can hardly communicate data accros.
With dev (creating some kind of Web part), we could achieve what you describe, but that would really be against the SharePoint "phylosophy"...

However, here's a simple "hack" you can easily do:

1. Navigate to the full calendar view on site B
2. Get the complete URL of the calendar view from the address bar
3. Add "?IsDlg=1" to the URL (this will prevent the menus/headers... all the chrome from appearing later in the iFrame we'll create at steps #4/#5) and copy the URL
4. Add a "Page viewer" Web part on site A
5. Set it to point to URL created/copied at step #3
6. Save the page

Answer (score 2):

1. Export the calendar list view as webpart from source location
2. Upload to webpart gallery of destination
3. Add the web part on a page of destination site

Assuming both are on same site collection.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using SP 2013 you do have the option to do calendar overlays, which will allow you to plug an offsite calendar into an existing site calendar and overlay it.  I've also done this in SP 2007 using a site feature (found on codeplex, i believe).

Answer (score 0):

Search can go across site collections, but you need to built your own rendering.