# Share a Calendar with another Sharepoint Site

Tags: calendar

I'm in an organization that does not have a global Sharepoint. My department (Department A) is attempting to adopt Sharepoint for our purposes. Another department (Department B) has been using Sharepoint for a few months now. They have a calendar on their site that is already Shared with all of the members of our department. However, we have our own Sharepoint site that we would like to display this calendar in. Despite each of us having the ability to see the calendar, I cannot seem to find a way to display the calendar in our Sharepoint site.

Is there a way for us in Department A to add a view for Department B's calendar in our Department A Sharepoint site?

Comment: To clarify: Department A and Departbment B sites are not related; they are not subsites of a parent site, unfortunately. That would be too easy!

Comment: Wow, so I just found this thread from a year ago. I swear I didn't see it before I asked this question! Has *very* similar wording; it would appear that this is not possible based on the answers from that. http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/164496/can-i-add-a-calendar-as-a-webpart-if-it-is-not-in-my-site?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

there are options to use calender overlays between sub sites in a site collection and they work great.